# how to differentiate safe mode and normal mode programmatically in android?

Tags: android, boot

I want to work with safe mode in android. How can I check whether the device is in safe mode or not programmatically?
Is it possible to set a password only for safe mode?

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the device has been booted in safe mode by the isSafeMode(), You can refer this link,
 https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#isSafeMode()